# Getting an image back from Lambda is not shown on windows outlook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, outlook, python-imaging-library

I have a lambda function that returns an image
When creating a new email with an image that its source is the lambda function i was able to see the image on all of the existing mail clients including linux and mac outlook
but on windows outlook it is not shown, I get a red X sign with the text "The picture can't be displayed"

any ideas what should be changed in the lambda's code in order to be able to see the image on Windows Outlook as well?

My Code:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from flask import Flask, request, send_file
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100))
    imgByteArr = BytesIO()
        format = 'JPEG'
        mimetype = 'image/jpg'
        img.save(imgByteArr, format=format, quality=90)
    imgByteArr.seek(0)
    return send_file(imgByteArr, mimetype=mimetype)
```

The Image code in the email:

```
<img style="display:block" src="my-lambda..." alt="" width="500" height="auto" border="0">
```

The Email on Windows outlook:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTML messages are rendered in Outlook by Word, and (at least in the older versions), it does not support msg tags with inlined image data.

You'd need to add the image as an attachment, set its `Content-ID` MIME header, and refer to that image in the HTML body through `<img src="cid:MyContenttId">`